# How can I copy entire directories and exclude specific files in Unix

Tags: unix, cp

I have a Unix batch script that copies the contents of one directory (call it dir A) to another (call it dir B).

Here is the copy statement I have currently.

```
cp -urL /path/to/dir/A /path/to/dir/B
```

However, this statement copies over hidden files.

How can I exclude any and all hidden files from being copied over?

Comment: Another option is using the rsync command to exclude hidden files

`rsync -a /path/to/source/dir/ /path/to/destination/dir --exclude='.*'` It took me an entire day to figure out how to get the rsync to work. Be sure to read the man. rsync can be tricky but it is very powerful.

Answer (score 6):

Put star (*) in to copy but ignore hidden files

```
cp -urL -r /path/to/dir/A/* /path/to/dir/B
```

Comment: Thanks ngduc, I do need a * at the end of the source directory path. Im a little confused with the '-r' Isn't the -r the same option as in     -urL?

Comment: -r is for recursive, look like u have 'r' in -urL :) you can remove it -r

Answer (score 3):

If using `bash` as your shell, unset the `dotglob` shell option.

#### From `man bash`

> **dotglob** If set, bash includes filenames beginning with a '.' in the
>   results of pathname expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -u dotglob
cp -urL /path/to/dir/A /path/to/dir/B
```

Comment: Does the dotglob need to be reset using the 'shopt -s dotglob' command? There are other users on the box and I don't want to confuse others by changing the behavior of bash. Does the dotglob setting only affect the commands called within the script?

Comment: @James It will only affect the shell script that contains it, not the rest of your users. You'd have to put it in `/etc/profile` or some such to make it global.

Comment: I can set the dotglob to false from the command line. And when I run     ' cp /path/to/dir/A/* /path/to/dir/B/ ' I get the desired results. However, with the dotglob set to false, when I run my script, I'm not getting the same results. Here is a snippet of my script.

#!/bin/bash
shopt -u dotglob
CUSTOMER_HOME=/customer/home/dir
FW_STAGING=/staging/home/dir
cp -urL $CUSTOMER_HOME/* $FW_STAGING/

I'm new to stackoverflow and I don't know how to edit code.

Comment: @James there is an `edit` link right under the `unix` and `cp` tags you chose.